# Unity: Initialize an object according to a condition

Tags: function, unity-game-engine, if-statement, initialization

I am pretty new to creating Custom Classes. I would like to know if I can use the if statement as part of the Function call.

What I have going on:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using UnityEngine;

public enum TokenType {Monster, Place, Spell}
public class Token
{
    public TokenType TokenType;
    public string TokenName;
    public string Description;
    public int Cost;
    public int Armor;
    public int Hp;
    public int Damage;
    public int MoveSpeed;
    public int AttackRange;
    public bool CanFly;
    public bool CanSpellcast;
    public int MultiAttackLvl;
    public bool IsElite;
    public bool CanFrightRoar;

    //Full Version
    public Token(TokenType tokenType, string tokenName, string description, int cost, int armor, int hp, int damage, int moveSpeed, int attackRange, bool canFly, bool canSpellcast, int multiAttackLvl, bool isElite, bool canFrightRoar)
    {
        TokenType = tokenType;
        TokenName = tokenName;
        Description = description;
        Cost = cost;
        Armor = armor;
        Hp = hp;
        Damage = damage;
        MoveSpeed = moveSpeed;
        AttackRange = attackRange;
        CanFly = canFly;
        CanSpellcast = canSpellcast;
        MultiAttackLvl = multiAttackLvl;
        IsElite = isElite;
        CanFrightRoar = canFrightRoar;
    }
    //Basic
    public Token(TokenType tokenType, string tokenName, string description, int cost, int armor, int hp, int damage, int moveSpeed, int attackRange)
    {
        TokenType = tokenType;
        TokenName = tokenName;
        Description = description;
        Cost = cost;
        Armor = armor;
        Hp = hp;
        Damage = damage;
        MoveSpeed = moveSpeed;
        AttackRange = attackRange;
        CanFly = false;
        CanSpellcast = false;
        MultiAttackLvl = 0;
        IsElite = false;
        CanFrightRoar = false;
    }
    //Flying
    public Token(TokenType tokenType, string tokenName, string description, int cost, int armor, int hp, int damage, int moveSpeed, int attackRange,bool canFly)
    {
        TokenType = tokenType;
        TokenName = tokenName;
        Description = description;
        Cost = cost;
        Armor = armor;
        Hp = hp;
        Damage = damage;
        MoveSpeed = moveSpeed;
        AttackRange = attackRange;
        CanFly = canFly;
        CanSpellcast = false;
        MultiAttackLvl = 0;
        IsElite = false;
        CanFrightRoar = false;
    }
}
```

I would like to use the if statement as

```
public Token(if(TokenType==TokenType.Place),string tokenName, string, descrition){}
```

Is it possible or do I have to find a different way to do this?

Don't wanna create a second special class just for Places or Spells because of the generality of my code.

Thanks for the answers.

Comment: It is not possible, and I don't really know why would you want to do this there. If you want to check token type and then act accordingly, just do it inside your method. If by chance you meant just a different argument list, you could use method overloading.

Comment: I tried to guess your intentions when I wrote my answer, so let me know if I'm wrong. You should provide more details in future questions so that people can more easily help!

Answer (score 0):

You have a class with a ton of data tied to it, which you want to configure in a few different ways for different objects in your game. This is the most common use case for [Scriptable Objects](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-ScriptableObject.html).

Additionally, a constructor with a ton of parameters is a sign [something is wrong](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/311322) with your design. You either want to split the responsibilities of this class into other classes, or send the list of parameters to the constructor through a container object. It's up to you to decide which is best for your project, but I'll use the latter in my example.

---

I'll split the fields of `Token` into `ScriptableObject`s through the following steps:

1. Grouping Parameters
2. Configuring Data
3. Assigning Data
4. Notes

### Grouping Parameters

Some of the parameters in the list can be grouped together. This fixes the huge parameter list and also provides a far more convenient way to pass around information about the `Token` object.

```
[CreateAssetMenu(fileName = "TokenIdentity", menuName = "Token Settings/Token Identity", order = 0)]
public class TokenIdentity : ScriptableObject
{
    public TokenType TokenType;
    public string TokenName;
    public string Description;
}
    
[CreateAssetMenu(fileName = "TokenData", menuName = "Token Settings/Token Data", order = 0)]
public class TokenData : ScriptableObject
{
    public int Cost;
    public int Armor;
    public int Hp;
    public int Damage;
    public int MoveSpeed;
    public int AttackRange;
}
    
[CreateAssetMenu(fileName = "TokenAbilities", menuName = "Token Settings/Token Abilities", order = 0)]
public class TokenAbilities : ScriptableObject
{
    public bool CanFly;
    public bool CanSpellcast;
    public int MultiAttackLvl;
    public bool IsElite;
    public bool CanFrightRoar;
}
```

Now your `Token` class can look like this:

```
public class Token
{
    public TokenIdentity IdentitySettings;
    public TokenData DefaultData;
    public TokenAbilities AbilitySettings;

    public Token(TokenIdentity id, TokenData data, TokenAbilities abilities)
    {
        IdentitySettings = id;
        DefaultData = data;
        AbilitySettings = abilities;
    }
}
```

### Configuring Data

Now we create the scriptable objects we just wrote. The `[CreateAssetMenu]` tag you see  on the class header is an attribute [defined by Unity](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/CreateAssetMenuAttribute.html). It adds your class to the asset menu according to the path in the `menuName` field. In the example, it's `Assets > Create > Token Settings`. You can create an instance of each of the three scriptable objects and add in the data you want to use for a certain type of token.

**Menu Path**

[image: menu path]

**`TokenIdentity` Instance for a Monster**

[image: monster identity]

**`TokenData` Instance for a Monster**

[image: monster data]

**`TokenAbilities` Instance for a Monster**

[image: monster abilities]

These screenshots show the configuration for a monster `Token`. You can create another set of scriptable objects for places, and a third set for spells.

### Assigning Data

Now we use these scriptable objects. When you clicked the create button in the asset menu, you should have seen the prompt for naming and saving the asset file. Assign that file to an instance of a `Token` object by dragging it into the appropriate field in the Unity editor.

[image: token with monster settings]

This instance of `Token` now uses the values set in the scriptable objects for monster! These values will be shared by any object that references the same scriptable objects. You can modify the values on the scriptable object and every token that uses it will reflect those changes.

### Notes

- You could group all the parameters into a single scriptable object instead of bothering with creating and configuring three of them for each type of `Token`.
- Each `ScriptableObject` implementation must be in its own .cs file with a matching name (Ex: TokenIdentity is in TokenIdentity.cs and TokenData is in TokenData.cs)
- Since data contained in a `ScriptableObject` is shared, each `Token` object should have a separate container for data that changes throughout gameplay. If a monster gets a damage buff or loses health, you don't want every monster to receive that change.

Comment: Hello and thank you. My intentions were simply to create a backbone database of Tokens from which I will take the necessary data for Creation/ Instantiating Tokens on Gameboard. Since I wanted to use List<T> as Database for simplicity and to keep my own sanity. What I am creating is a mash of Card game elements with hints of strategy and Turn-based combat.

I will try your answer and check back with you on how it worked.

Comment: Mainly I wanted to avoid creating a prefab for each Card/Token since there might be too many to keep track of them all. And potentially save some storage space. That was my line of thinking. But it seems like I don't have a better choice other than doing so.

Comment: @brutgag Yes, that confirms scriptable objects should be a good solution for you. You can use the [factory pattern](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) and feed in a list of scriptable objects that contain the configuration for each object. You won't need a prefab for every object because the factory will be responsible for managing how the objects are created, instantiated, and possibly even recycled. Good luck!